# How to check contact read email or not when send email to Individual?

Tags: wordpress, email

I'm using WordPress 4.9.8, CiviCRM to 5.5.1, I usually send email to contact by

1. Search> Find contacts
2. View contact details
3. Action> Send email
4. Send email ok, Contact received mail ok like picture

   [image]

But status only Email sent though contact read email or not. So, can CiviCRM can change status to **Email read** when contact read email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to try installing the [Transactional Emails](https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.transactional/) extension which aims to address the limitation of CiviCRM which only handles the tracking of emails sent through civimail.

This extension tracks bounce, click, open events for single emails sent from civicrm, either with `Send Email` action, scheduled reminders, contribution receipts, etc.

The description on the extension link explains in detail on how to install and check the report of these events.

Comment: I've install Transactional Emails extension successfully and send test email, but still don't find out how to check email open or not (I've read in the extension link you've send). Please show me how to check on CiviCRM.

Comment: This is same as we follow for civimail tracking. A new mailing would be created at `civicrm/mailing/browse/scheduled?reset=1&scheduled=true`. Click on the report link to check the tracking results.

Comment: Thank you, I've check this report in WordPress is Mailings> Mailing Reports> Choose report link: wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Freport%2Flist&compid=4&reset=1. I've marked your andswer is solution. Thanks.

Comment: I have another small problem:
1. Mailing Name is Transactional Email (Activity Email Sender) but Mailing Subject is empty
2. Time read Open email is not exactly
How can I fix this?

Comment: Activity Subject will be shown when you open the mailing report. You can see the contact list that were a part of activity mailings and also the details of activity that was sent.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to look into your email server/ SMTP provider to check on the status of an email as the send email action (up to 50 contacts) does not currently offer the ability to track this information.

Sorry not to have been of more help,
Tamar